# Is there a faster way to store a big dictionary, than pickle or regular Python file?

Tags: python, pickle

I want to store a dictionary which only contains data in the following format:

```
{
    "key1" : True,
    "key2" : True,
    .....
}
```

In other words, just a quick way to check if a key is valid or not. I can do this by storing a dict called `foo` in a file called `bar.py`, and then in my other modules, I can import it as follows:

```
from bar import foo
```

Or, I can save it in a pickle file called `bar.pickle`, and import it at the top of the file as follows:

```
import pickle  
with open('bar.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    foo = pickle.load(f)
```

Which would be the ideal, and **faster** way to do this?

Comment: pickle is a just a binary format which can help you to save dict more efficiently. Python definitely needs to spend a little bit more effort to read/parse binary format than plain text format.

Comment: there are lots of alternatives here, what's best/ideal/fastest almost certainly depends on much more information than you've given.  i.e. how often does this data change, who changes it, how do they change it, do you want to keep track of these changes, do you care about portability to different systems/versions of Python… and many more

Comment: You could also consider dumping it as a `json` since the format is essentially the same, unless your dictionary have other Python object inside that is.

Comment: If you don't have any need to distinguish between `False` and varieties of N/A, you can just create a list of the keys with `True` values and write that to file. Then instead of doing `if my_dict[key]`, you can do `if key in my_list`.

Comment: @Acccumulation but that would be trading an O(1) membership test for an O(N) membership test.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `s/list/set/` in Acccumulation's comment and it's O(1) as well.

Comment: @spectras sure, a `set` seems reasonable. There may be *some* advantages to using a `dict` of booleans, which is almost essentially like a `set`. But I don't really know the details enough to say what I would prefer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Python File**

Using a python file will easily cache the dictionary, so that if you "import" it multiple times, it only has to be parsed once. However, python syntax is complicated, and so the parser that loads the file may not be well optimized for the limited complexity of the data you're saving (unless you're including arbitrary Python objects and code). It's easy to view and edit, and easy to use, but it's not easy to transport.

EDIT: to clarify, raw Python files are easy for a human to modify, but very hard for a computer to edit. If your code edits the data and you ever want that to be reflected in the dictionary, you're pretty much up a creek: instead, use one of the methods below.

**Pickle File**

If you use a pickle file, you'd either re-load the file each time you use it, or need some management code to cache the file after reading it the first time. Like arbitrary Python code, pickle files can be quite complex and the loader for them might not be optimized for your particular data types since, like raw python files, they can also store most arbitrary Python objects. However, they're hard to edit and view for a regular human, and you might encounter portability issues if you move the data around. It's also only readable by Python, and you need to consider the security considerations of using pickle, since loading pickle files can be risky and should only be done with trusted files.

**JSON File**

If all you're storing is simple objects (dictionaries, lists, strings, booleans, numbers), consider using the JSON file format. Python has a built-in `json` module that's just as easy to use as `pickle`, so there's no added complexity. These files are easy to store, view, edit, and compress (if desired), and look almost exactly like a python dictionary. It's highly portable (most common languages support reading/writing JSON files these days), and if you need to improve file loading speed, the `ujson` module is a faster, drop-in replacement for the standard `json` module. Since the JSON file format is fairly restricted, I'd expect its parsers and writers to be quite a bit faster than the regular Python or Pickle parsers (especially using `ujson`).

Comment: Yes, yes and yes, please use a common format such as json. It's not just faster, it's also safer, portable, human-readable, re-usable…

Comment: I wouldn't consider `json` exactly human-readable (beyond the literal definition)... after all that's why [hjson](https://hjson.org/) exists.  But I do agree on using a common format like itself.

Comment: YMMV, it's *reasonably* human-readable while *reasonably* fast. Requirements will certainly shift the cursor. I wouldn't use json for any file intended to be written by a human. Nor would I use it for performance-critical serialization. Probably I'd use YAML for the former and FlatBuffers for the latter, or something along those lines. JSON is a good in-the-middle general-purpose data format :)

Comment: Agreed, YAML is a great format for human readability, and custom formats like FlatBuffers and Protobuf are great for performance and serialization size. However, support for YAML is a bit more spotty (even Python needs a third party module to read it), and custom binary formats often involve more setup (e.g. defining and compiling the data structure in advance). JSON is a great compromise, being extremely easy to use in general, and (if formatted properly) easy to read/write. It's a good next step for people who don't want to get swamped in all the possible serialization methods.

Answer (score 11):

To add to @scnerd's comment, here are the timings in IPython for different load situations.

Here we create a dictionary and write it to 3 formats:

```
import random
import json
import pickle

letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
d = {''.join(random.choices(letters, k=6)): random.choice([True, False]) 
     for _ in range(100000)}

# write a python file
with open('mydict.py', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('d = {\n')
    for k,v in d.items():
        fp.write(f"'{k}':{v},\n")
    fp.write('None:False}')

# write a pickle file
with open('mydict.pickle', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(d, fp)

# write a json file
with open('mydict.json', 'wb') as fp:
    json.dump(d, fp)
```

#### Python file:

```
# on first import the file will be cached.  
%%timeit -n1 -r1
from mydict import d

644 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

# after creating the __pycache__ folder, import is MUCH faster
%%timeit
from mydict import d

1.37 µs ± 54.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

#### pickle file:

```
%%timeit
with open('mydict.pickle', 'rb') as fp:
    pickle.load(fp)

52.4 ms ± 1.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### json file:

```
%%timeit
with open('mydict.json', 'rb') as fp:
    json.load(fp)

81.3 ms ± 2.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# here is the same test with ujson
import ujson

%%timeit
with open('mydict.json', 'rb') as fp:
    ujson.load(fp)

51.2 ms ± 304 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Since I did specifically mention ``ujson`` to improve json speed, could you add a timing with that as well?

Comment: Also, for the Python file, you don't need the ``None: False`` at the end, at least in Python 3.6+ (probably any 3.X, not sure), it's valid syntax to have an extra comma at the end of a dictionary literal

Comment: Oh!  Did not know that.

Comment: Added the `ujson` test.  It looks comparable to using pickle.